# how to serialize arbitrary file types to json string in python

Tags: python, json, serialization

My server is going to be sending a JSON, serialized as a string, through a socket to another client machine. I'll take my final json and do this:

```
import json
python_dict_obj = { "id" : 1001, "name" : "something", "file" : <???> }
serialized_json_str = json.dumps(python_dict_obj)
```

I'd like to have one of the fields in my JSON have the value that is a file, encoded as a string.

Performance-wise (but also interoperability-wise) what is the best way to encode a file using python? Base64? Binary? Just the raw string text?

EDIT - For those suggestion base64, something like this?

```
# get file
import base64
import json

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    filecontents = f.read()
encoded = base64.b64encode(filecontents)
python_dict_obj['file'] = encoded
serialized_json_str = json.dumps(python_dict_obj)

# ... sent to client via socket

# decrpyting
json_again = json.loads(serialized)
filecontents_again = base64.b64decode(json_again['file'])
```

Comment: In python 3.5, I needed to do one more encode to get a string in my dict. `python_dict_obj['file'] = encoded.encode()`. Otherwise, the value was a binary `b'something'` which caused an error during `json.dumps`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use `base64`.  JSON isn't designed to communicate binary data.  So unless your file's content is vanilla text, it "should be" encoded to use vanilla text.  Virtually everything can encode and decode `base64`.  If you instead use (for example) Python's `repr(file_content)`, that also produces "plain text", but the receiving end would need to know how to decode the string escapes Python's `repr()` uses.

Comment: Well, on the decoding side, you'd get `filecontents` from some spelling of `json.loads()`.  After that, you're done with JSON.  The `base64` decoder applied to `filecontents` will give you back the original binary file contents.  Try it!  This is easier to do than to explain ;-)

Comment: Oops!  After your latest edit, I think you figured it out :-)

Answer (score 3):

JSON cannot handle binary. You will need to encode the data as text before serializing, and the easiest to encode it as is Base64. You do not need to use the URL-safe form of encoding unless there are requirements for it further down the processing chain.

Comment: Is it also worth base64 encoding the entire json string as well too?

Comment: Only if something further down the chain requires it. But JSON is plain text regardless (except regarding `ensure_ascii`, but that's a different issue which you'll either already know how to handle or can safely ignore).

Comment: so I wouldn't gain any size reduction by doing that? (base64 encoding file then base64 encoding surrounding json as well)

Comment: No size reduction:  `base64` encoding generally **increases** the number of bytes needed.  After all, it's only using 6 of each 8 bits per byte (2**6 == 64, the number of distinct possible values in a `base64` encoding).

Comment: Encoding as Base64 *increases* the size of the data by 33%.