# Is there a type of file where to write both text and images?

Tags: python, file-handling

I am trying to automatically write reports in python. These reports contain both text and images. Is there a way I could write successively text and put images in a file using python?

Comment: I 'd suggest taking a look at jupyter notebooks.

Comment: I'll check if I can export a jupyter notebook to a pdf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the file data is also just plain text. The only problem is how to parse the reports e.g. differ plain text from file data.

You could use the JSON library to parse such reports. Since JSON cannot not deal with raw binary data you might encode the strings to base64 first

```
data.encode('base64')
```

Here are some related topics on that problem:

- [How to include pictures bytes to a JSON with python? (encoding issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837346/how-to-include-pictures-bytes-to-a-json-with-python-encoding-issue)
- [how to serialize arbitrary file types to json string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149972/how-to-serialize-arbitrary-file-types-to-json-string-in-python)

If there are images within the report one could also use HTML as jasonharper suggested:

- [HTML5 using src using raw binary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645223/html5-using-src-using-raw-binary-data)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a HTML file, using Base64 to encode images directly into the `<img>` tags rather than referring to files elsewhere.

You could use a PDF generation toolkit such as [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com).